# Append a counter to multiple identical column words only in the first line of a file with Java

Tags: java, csv, replace, text-files, randomaccessfile

I want to access only the first line of a huge textfile (.txt/.csv) to change repetetive words by appending a counter and write it back.

In other words: There are multiple identical columns names in the texfile header which need to be changed before importing into another system.

The example input is:
Col1, Col2, WWAB., WWAB., WWAB., WWAB., WWCD., WWCD., WWCD., Column99

As an example the textfile named *mytest.txt* looks like this:
Col1, Col2, WWAB., WWAB., WWAB., WWAB., WWCD., WWCD., WWCD., Column99
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J

My example code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;

public class ChangeTextFileHeader {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
RandomAccessFile raFile = null;

raFile = new RandomAccessFile("C:/mytest.txt", "rw"); // define File with read/write permission
int i;
String strOut;
raFile.seek(0); // sets pointer to the start of text
String csvHeader = raFile.readLine(); // read the first line (Header)
System.out.println("Header: " + csvHeader); // show original Header

for (i = 1; i <= 5; i = i + 1) {
    raFile.seek(0); // start pointer
    //replace textparts with counter
    strOut = csvHeader;
    strOut = strOut.replaceFirst("WWAB.", "WWAB" + i).replaceFirst("WWCD.", "WWCD" + i);
    System.out.println("Loop "+i+": " + strOut); // show original Header
    raFile.writeBytes(strOut); // write changes and continue from start
    }

raFile.seek(0);
System.out.println("Result: " + raFile.readLine()); //show result of written Header
raFile.close(); //close File
```

}
}

Example Output should be:
Col1, Col2, WWAB1, WWAB2, WWAB3, WWAB4, WWCD1, WWCD2, WWCD3, Column99

Unfortunatly it produces:
Col1, Col2, WWAB5, WWAB., WWAB., WWAB., WWCD5, WWCD., WWCD., Column99

Please show me your working code. Thank you.

Comment: `String::replaceFirst` uses a regular expression as its first parameter.  So `WWCD.` will match WWCD., WWCD1, WWCD2, etc.  Escape the dot character with a backslash: `WWCD\.`

Comment: That didn't work. I tried a "WWCD\\." (double backslash) and it was the same result:
Col1, Col2, WWAB5, WWAB., WWAB., WWAB., WWCD5, WWCD., WWCD., Column99

Comment: Sorry, there were more issues with the code sample.  `strOut = csvHeader;` inside the loop is clobbering the changes made in the `replaceFirst` line.  It really replaces on the first line five times. (Since `csvHeader` was assigned once outside and before the loop and `strOut` becomes `csvHeader` every iteration.)  I would post a full answer but it looks like forpas beat me to it!

Comment: No problem and thank you for your key input about the dot character! Forpas gave a good working solution and I will adapt some parts of it in the future. I also posted my fixed original code below with the use of RandomAccessFile :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `replaceFirst()` takes as 1st parameter a regular expression 
and when you do

```
replaceFirst("WWAB.", "WWAB" + i)
```

the dot `.` means **any character**! 
After the 1st match when `WWAB.` is replaced with `WWAB1` 
`WWAB1` is matched again and replaced with `WWAB2` and so on. 
So one solution is to replace each `.` with another character before starting the replacements, like:

```
strOut = strOut.replace(".", "@");
```

and then search and replace `WWAB@`.  
I did not reproduce your code, as I find easier the following solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file = new File("C:/mytest.txt");
    List<String> lines;
    try {
        lines = new ArrayList<>(Files.readAllLines(file.toPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    if (lines.size() == 0)
        return;

    String firstLine = lines.get(0).trim();
    if (firstLine.isEmpty())
        return;

    char c = '@';
    firstLine = firstLine.replace('.', c);
    String[] toReplace = {"WWAB", "WWCD"};

    for (String s : toReplace) {
        int j = 0;
        while (firstLine.contains(s + c)) {
            j++;
            firstLine = firstLine.replaceFirst(s + c, s + j);
        }
    }

    lines.set(0, firstLine);

    try {
        Files.write(file.toPath(), lines, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//this is how i quickly fixed my original code with the help of this community
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;

public class ChangeTextFileHeader {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

RandomAccessFile raFile = null;
int i;

raFile = new RandomAccessFile("c:/mytest.txt", "rw"); // define file with read/write permission
raFile.seek(0); // set start pointer of filestream
String csvHeader = raFile.readLine(); // read the first line (=header)
System.out.println("Header: " + csvHeader); // show original header

csvHeader = csvHeader.replaceAll("\\.","@"); //replace all dots in header (a dot means "any character")
raFile.seek(0); // (re)set start pointer of filestream

for (i = 1; i <= 5; i = i + 1) {
csvHeader = csvHeader.replaceFirst("WWAB@", "WWAB" + i).replaceFirst("WWCD@", "WWCD" + i); //replace textparts with counter
System.out.println("Loop " + i + ": " + csvHeader); // show current header
raFile.writeBytes(csvHeader); // write changes of replace
raFile.seek(0); // goto start of filestream again to search next replace in the loop
}

System.out.println("Result: " + csvHeader); // show result of modified header
raFile.close(); //close filestream

 }
}
```